# Delete first word before bracket Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to

```
 var sortedArtists = function(nodes,links)
```

turn in to

```
var sortedArtists = (nodes,links)=>
```

I wanna to delete parenthesis only after function keyword.
How can I do it with regexp?

Comment: Is `function(nodes,links)` suppose to be a string?

Comment: You said `I wanna to delete parenthesis only after function keyword.` but your expected result keep parenthesis! What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways here, one of them being

```
\S+\(([^()]+)\)
```

This needs to be replaced by `($1)=>`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/C3YlQd/1/).

Comment: Thaknks but I try in notepad++ and it give me    var sortedArtists = nodes,links=>

Comment: Anyway there is another problem. It deletes everythig in all parenthesis. But I need to rewrite my post

Comment: Like it says in this answer, you need to interpolate the captured text `$1` back into the replacement.  It's hard to give detailed advice when your question doesn't mention which tool you are using; regex facilities vary enormously between implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to go the regex way. From what I can understand, you are trying to convert es5 code to es6. The best way to do it will be using a library like [lebab](https://lebab.io/try-it)

This will convert your code

```
var sortedArtists = function(nodes,links){
}
```

to

```
const sortedArtists = (nodes, links) => {
};
```

Comment: Yes, But I`m just interesting. And I wanna delete all function keyword.

Comment: this is not my goal.